# CloseableHttpClient blocks per few minutes under high concurrency

Tags: apache-httpcomponents

I am using httpcomponents to do http requests. I have set the `connectionRequestTimeout`, `connectTimeout` and `socketTimeout` to the same time(such as 8000ms). The system is in a high concurrency and most time it performs well, but some requests cost seconds which is the same as the timeout(~8000ms) per minutes. Here is the code snippet:

```
    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectionRequestTimeout(TIMEOUT).setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT).setSocketTimeout(TIMEOUT).build();
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();
    HttpUriRequest request = null;
    switch (method) {
        case GET:
            String getUrl = url;
            if (null != paramData) {
                getUrl += "?" + paramData;
            }
            request = new HttpGet(getUrl);
            break;
        case POST:
            ...
        default:
            ...
    }
    CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        response = client.execute(request);
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        // ***************************
        // Sometime the log shows the cost is a few milliseconds more than TIMEOUT,
        // but it does not throw any timeout exception and the response is fine.
        // ***************************
        LOG.debug("cost {}ms", time);
        int resultCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String resultJson = EntityUtils.toString(entity, UTF_8);
        if (HttpStatus.SC_OK == resultCode) {
            ...
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    } finally {
        //abort the request
        if (null != request && !request.isAborted()) {
            request.abort();
        }
        //close the connection
        HttpClientUtils.closeQuietly(client);
        HttpClientUtils.closeQuietly(response);
    }
```

The version of httpcomponents is 4.5.2 and the jdk is openjdk 1.8.0_92.
Moreover, should I use `CloseableHttpClient` as a singleton for better performance?

Comment: This problem has been resolved by making `CloseableHttpClient` as a singleton. I think it's very expensive to `new` a client for every http request. BTW, we should not `close` the `CloseableHttpClient` if we want to reuse the client.

Comment: Can you please accept the below answer? It will help others solve their similar problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CloseableHttpClient` should be used singleton for better performance.
You can also define the number of connection as per your requirement in `HttpClientBuilder`.

Also socketTimeout should be more that connectionTimeOut, This will give more time to read the socket.